# afnetworking request parameter sequence

Tags: objective-c, httprequest, afnetworking-2

I am trying to produce a request using afnetworking in objective c, however, it seems like the hardware that I am trying to connect to only applies requests when the parameters of the request are in a specific order. So I am wondering if there is a way to make the request so that the parameters are in a specific order. (As just doing it normally seems to jumble the sequence of the params up)

Here's my code:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                         @"param1" : @"bla",
                         @"param2" : @"bla2",
                         @"param3" : @"bla3"
                         };

[requestManager GET:@"somewhere" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                DLog(@"Success!");
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                DLog(@"Fail: %@", error);
            }];
```

It actually goes to success every time, its just that the request I had applied would be practically ignored.

The actual request body becomes something like "param3=bla3&param1=bla1&param2=bla2 etc which would be ignored as it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using the request manager in the way you currently are.

Instead, you would need to create the parameter list yourself, and then create a request from that. Then you could use AFN to handle the request transmission and response.

Note that the server shouldn't require a specific order and that this should be changed if possible. Note also that the dictionary of parameters has no order (even though you add the keys in a set order).

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot change the server (a 3rd party hardware), I wish I could! I managed to fix the problem by making a string and including it in the @"somewhere%@" since it is a GET request, but thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the order of the parameters have a great impact on server performance. This sounds silly at first, but just think about GET requests which contain the query string as part of the URL. Web servers can cache the response for the given URL. If you mess with the order of the parameters, the cache won't be as effective as it could be.

The case is even worse if you call an API from different platforms (iOS, Android, Web) and they all reorder the params, which means that the same content will be found on 3 different cache keys.

Keeping the order is a performance issue at the first place.